# Python: How to correctly loop this edit in jinja2

Tags: python, loops, datetime, data-structures, jinja2

Not really sure how to loop this, I thought passing it through a function might be best but I was told to try and not do that if possible.

Here is what I'm trying to do (front.py):

```
class Front( handler.Handler ):

    def get( self ):
        query = b1data.b2data.all()

        # Here is what I'm trying to print for each entry
        for a2 in query:
            # the dates are: 2013-10-05 03:00:00 and 2014-01-07 03:00:00
            b = datetime.strptime(a2.date_airingdate, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
            a = datetime.now()
            totaldays = (a-b).days
            allweeks = totaldays / 7 + 1

        self.render("front.html", allweeks=allweeks, query=query)
```

And here is my front.html

```
{% for a2 in query %}
 <tr class="header">
  <td>{{ a2.somename }}</td>
    <td>{{ allweeks }}</td>
   </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

This just prints for 1 (the first) entry, how would I get this for each entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd leave all of my logic inside the handler, construct a list of dictionaries and pass it into the template:

```
class Front(handler.Handler):
    def get(self):
        data = []
        now = datetime.now()
        for item in b1data.b2data.all():
            airingdate = datetime.strptime(item.date_airingdate, 
                                           '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
            data.append({'allweeks': (now - airingdate).days / 7 + 1,
                         'somename': item.somename})

        self.render("front.html", data=data)
```

Then, showing the data in the template is pretty straight-forward:

```
{% for item in data %}
    <tr class="header">
        <td>{{ item.somename }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.allweeks }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Also, note that you should put as less things in a loop as you possibly can. For example, why call `datetime.now()` in the loop - instead, call it once before the loop and reuse.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Taken a bit to get it work with my other code (was a mess on my end) but it works great! Will be using this way for a lot of things thanks!